# IE9 "Invalid calling object" when printing PDF in iframe

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, acrobat

I'm opening an editable form PDF (opened via the acrobat plugin) in an iframe:

```
<iframe name="iframe_content" id="iframe_content" src="mypdf.pdf"></iframe>
```

There is a button that calls the following print function:

```
function printContent(){
    window.frames["iframe_content"].focus();
    window.frames["iframe_content"].print();
}
```

It works in Chrome, Safari, IE8, but not in IE9.
In IE9 i receive the following error in reference to the `printContent()` function:

```
Invalid calling object
```

I think this may be the trick to getting it to work, but I'm not sure how to make `window.frames` fit within this structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**UPDATE**: Decided that for this single page the simplest solution was forcing the browser into IE8 compatibility mode using the `<meta>` tag and `X-UA-Compatible`

Answer (score -3):

You must put your print function inside the Iframe's page and call it from the parent page.

in Iframe:

```
function printMe() {
    window.print()
}
```

in parent (assuming this is the first iframe on your page):

```
frames[0].printMe()
```

Comment: The issue is really with "Invalid calling object" on window.frames["iframe_content"]. I'm looking for a workaround for that issue. How do I make window.frames a valid calling object?

Comment: On IE I imagine that the PDF takes over the iframe at an application-level though active-x - so there is no web page there anymore. Just the PDF viewer.

Comment: Ended up just forcing the browser into IE8 compatibility mode. Not the best solution, but it works :p